# Loop in Live Templates PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

How does one make a live template in PyCharm, such that it fits this description:
Say one wishes to make an automated way of making tuples. So, one types in `tuple#`, where `#` is a number. and it will create something like this:

```
$someTuple$ = (
    '', * # number of times
)
```

Or better yet, type something like `makeTuple`, and it will make something like this:

```
$someTuple$ = (
    '$somevalue here$',
) $END$
```

and as long as you keep pressing `[tab]`, you can keep on creating new tuples. Once you press `[enter]`, it will stop, and come to `$END$`

Comment: Live templates do not support loops, see the [related request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5636).